# Sencha Touch TabPanel fires show event on all children on load

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have a tabpanel with 4 lists as child items. When each list is shown I want to load it's data. When I launch the app all 4 show events fire even though only the first tab is active. Is this how it's supposed to be? I could use activeitemchange of the tabpanel to populate the lists but I want to keep the code separate for each list. It doesn't make sense having the tabpanel control it's child items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's another event call 'painted' which fires whenever a component as actually shown to the user. I don't know what the difference between 'show' and 'painted' is but this seems to fix my problem.